# Missing framework XCTest

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, frameworks, xcode6

since latest XCODE 6 update my XCTest framework dissappeared from Developer/Library/Frameworks dir.
Is there any way to get this framework back? I can only see the SentestingKit there, which I don't want to use since I moved to XCTests/Kiwi tests

The project's FRAMEWORK SEARCH PATHS are set as they should ->

[image: My framework search paths looks like this]

EDIT:
I've also added $(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks to my test target's framework search paths

Answer (score 3):

In your Test Target, make sure Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags is set to "-framework XCTest"

Also make sure these are set (In Test Target):

Build Settings -> Linking -> Packaging -> Private Headers Folder Path = $(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/PrivateHeaders

Build Settings -> Linking -> Packaging -> Public Headers Folder Path = $(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Headers

Build Settings -> Linking -> Packaging -> Wrapper Extension = xctest

Comment: these things are already set in my test target. I forget to mention that my project was created way back, when 3.2 was out.

Comment: Ok I've sort it out. I'm currently using Kiwi, which headers file were referenced in my main target(which I assumed are referenced in the test target). It was so easy, I was a litlle bit blind at this one. Anyway thanks for your help Coveloper;)

Comment: I followed all the instructions here and in other threads but I keep not seeing the XCTest.framework library and, possibly as a consequence, getting IDEBundleInjection.c: Error 3587 when trying to execute the test.